# How to say when some pointy objects are hitting me

Tags: word-request, verbs

How do I say when some point objects are hitting me?  I mean what is the word for it.... Like when there are so many spikes and then it hits or irritates you... What is the actual word for it.... Should I say "the spike hit me" or "the spike poked" or what else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases I would use the verb "prick", since the objects you mention are sharp.

But depending on the force, the object might "pierce" you.

They could also "poke through" you, "stab" you, "impale" you or "prong" you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible words, but not necessarily *hit*. *Hit* works if, for example, someone takes a spike and throws it at you and you are struck, especially with a dull part of the spike. I doubt this is what you intended.

*Poke* is possible, but it suggests to me a light touch without an injury (although you can poke a hole into something).  You could consider *prick, stab, stick,* or even *pierce*, among others, if you are injured because the pointy end penetrated your skin.

> - [prick](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prick)
>     1 : to pierce slightly with a sharp point
> - [stab](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stab)
>     1 : to wound or pierce by the thrust of a pointed object or weapon
> - [stick](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick)
>     1 a : to pierce with something pointed : stab
> - [pierce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pierce)
>     1 a : to run into or through as a pointed weapon does : stab
>     b : to enter or thrust into sharply or painfully
>
> (M-W)

I would say that for something like a needle that lightly pierced you, you would use *prick*. If the needle, or something like a knife, was forcefully thrust into you, you could use *stab*.

If you mean, for example, that the spike dragged across your skin and irritated it, then you could consider *scratch*, *scrape*, or *graze*.

> - [scratch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scratch)
>     1 : to scrape or dig with the claws or nails
> - [scrape](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrape)
>     2 b : to damage or injure the surface of by contact with a rough surface
> - [graze](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graze)
>     2 : abrade, scratch • grazed her knee when she fell
>
> (M-W)